# WPF UserControls: Dependency Property or DataContext?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, dependency-properties, datacontext

Firstly I hope this question does not violate the rules, sorry in advance if it does.

I just just had a discussion with a colleague regarding the way we have been designing and implementing our user controls. We have been creating views which expect a certain data type, yet don't enforce that expectation and I feel this is the wrong approach. Controls are instantiated by assigning a value to the DataContext, but since that is of type Object, not only is there no data type enforcement, but it is also beginning to become very hard to see what data type is being passed to the control (because often a control is nested several layers under other user controls implemented in the same fashion).

My proposal was to instead have a dependency property which we will use instead of the DataContext. Internally, the user control, could set it's DataContext to this dependency property. This seems like not only the best approach, but also the unwritten standard in WPF.

My colleague is concerned this could cause difficulties down the road since it less flexible than using an DataContext (type Object).

I plan to bring this up again at our next software meeting, are there any books/websites you could recommend to help argue for one case or the other?

TLDR; Which is more correct?

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyCustomViewModel}">
        <vw:MyCustomView />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Or

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyCustomViewModel}">
        <vw:MyCustomView Value="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I would say first one. WPF is suppose to be not strong typed. You are responsible to provide the right value to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague has found a good compromise that allows him to consumer the user controls in the same way he has been, but allows me to enforce a datatype (and tell at glance what the expected type should be). Here is  a link to the solution that we will be using from now on: http://graemehill.ca/specifying-expected-datacontext-type-in-wpf/